# Is it possible to SEND a parse push notification from a the simulator?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I know it's not possible to receive push notifications on the simulator but is it possible to send them? Noticed that the simulator won't create an installation on Parse.com but does this make a difference?

thanks

Comment: Simulator does create an installation, and what do you mean sending? With PFPush?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you **CAN**

**BUT**

You cannot fully test push notifications in Xcode's simulator. You can send pushes from the simulator, but **it will not receive push notifications**.

Apple does not support Push Notifications through the iOS Simulator.

Comment: Yeah this is right. Can send pushes but not receive via the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

First you can't register to APNS with simulator So you can receive or send push notification from simulator , you need real device